# Unable to automate the Dailymotion upload page with large files using PhantomJS/CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have made 2 PhantomJS/CasperJS scripts because I am trying to develop an open source video uploader for multiple platforms.

The problem is that for Dailymotion, the script works with tiny files, but not with large files.

Here is the test PhantomJS script:

```
var page = new WebPage(), testindex = 0, loadInProgress = false;
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0';
page.viewportSize = {
  width: 2560,
  height: 1440
};
page.customHeaders = {
  "Accept": "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml, q=0.9, */*, q=0.8",
  "Accept-Language": "fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
  "Referer": "http://www.dailymotion.com/fr",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
};
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
  loadInProgress = true;
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  loadInProgress = false;
};

page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
    var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];
    if (trace && trace.length) {
        msgStack.push('TRACE:');
        trace.forEach(function(t) {
            msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function + '")' : ''));
        });
    }
    // uncomment to log into the console 
    // console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
};

var steps = [
  function() {
    //Load Login Page
    page.open("http://www.dailymotion.com/widget/upload/?skin=fog");
  },
  function() {
      page.evaluate(function() {
      var form = document.getElementById("login_form");
      form.elements["username"].value="Nemsis1990";
      form.elements["password"].value="20051965";
      form.submit();
    });
  },
function() {
    //Load Login Page
    page.open("http://www.dailymotion.com/upload");
  },
  function() {
    console.log("Uploading file..");
    page.uploadFile('input[type=file]', '/users/jabassar/Desktop/sample2.mp4');
  },
  function () {
    page.render("test.png");
  }
];


interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[testindex] == "function") {
    //console.log("Step " + (testindex + 1) + " completed.");
    steps[testindex]();
    testindex++;
  }
  if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
    //console.log("Task finished");
    phantom.exit();
  }
}, 10000);

function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 30000000, //< Default Max Timout is 3s
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if(!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 1000); //< repeat check every 250ms
};
```

Here is the test CasperJS script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://www.dailymotion.com/widget/upload/?skin=fog', function() {
    casper.fill('form[id="login_form"]', {
        'username': 'Nemsis1990',
        'password': '20051965'
    ,}, true);
    this.wait(2000);
});

casper.thenOpen('http://www.dailymotion.com/upload', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.then(function() {
  this.page.uploadFile('input[type=file]', '/users/jabassar/Desktop/sample2.mp4');
});

casper.then(function() {
  this.wait(30000);
  this.capture('test2.png');
});

casper.run();
```

So it works with this tiny (2mb) file:

```
http://sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4
```

But it doesn't work this large file:

```
http://sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4
```

Dailymotion says (javascript log):

```
CHUNK FAIL [object Object] [object Object]
ERROR!!!!
CHUNK FAIL [object Object] [object Object]
ERROR!!!!
CHUNK FAIL [object Object] [object Object]
ERROR!!!!
CHUNK FAIL [object Object] [object Object]
ERROR!!!!
```

(The 2.0.0 phantomjs uploadFile is bugged, so I use 1.9.8)

Could you please help me?

PS: PhantomJS must run with --web-security=false otherwise it throws warnings.

Comment: PhantomJS has arbitrary limitation that uploads cannot be longer than 30 seconds. Maybe this is the same problem as yours.

Comment: No, it doesn't even start the upload.

Comment: This might be related, but 20 KB seems a little low: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691780/phantomjs-file-upload-fails-if-file-is-larger-than-20000-bytes

Comment: No, I used to upload 600mb files with phantomjs, but this form is special.